# C# replace part of the message

Tags: c#, regex

```
string message = "Your purchase of $ 100.00 is awaiting for confirmation. Please use PIN 8967 to complete the transaction. Reference Number :1237689";

string output = Regex.Replace(message, @"[\d-]", "*");

Console.WriteLine("Message : " + message);

Console.WriteLine("Output : " + output);

Console.ReadLine();
```

I want to only replace the PIN of the message. But above message replace all the numeric values from * characters.

Comment: Use RegEx `(PIN )\d+` and replace with `$1 ****`.

Answer (score 3):

```
string message = "Your purchase of $ 100.00 is awaiting for confirmation. Please use PIN 8967 to complete the transaction. Reference Number :1237689";
string output = Regex.Replace(message, @"(?<=PIN\s*\d*)\d", "*");
```

or

```
string message = "Your purchase of $ 100.00 is awaiting for confirmation. Please use PIN 8967 to complete the transaction. Reference Number :1237689";
string output = Regex.Replace(message, @"(?<=PIN\s*)\d+", m => new string('*', m.Length));
```

Comment: Hi Ulugbek, Thanks for the guidance. It's works nicely.

Comment: @DreamCoder Please consider upvoting and marking the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi i doing above replace within the for loop. All the messages are in different format. If message like following it's not replace with * character. string message = "Your PIN has been reset. New PIN 347689 to log in."; so I need solution for the both scenarios.

Comment: @DreamCoder So you don't want to hide PIN if it is preceded by 'New PIN', right? Because the given regex hides PIN in it successfully.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov I want to hide the PIN from the messages. Above I sent the two type of messages. In the customer notifications need to hide the PIN. If message contains PIN then need to hide it.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov I refer above link. It's work fine. But not for me